# Converting an Array of Strings to HTML using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

can anyone help me with the proper way to iterate over an array of strings, that will then be placed in a paragraph tag using Reactjs?

The array looks something like:

```
names = [ "James", "Susan", "Frank" ];
```

### Here is my react component called "Riders" (I've added comments for help on what I'm trying to do):

```
import React from 'react';

import { Drivers } from '../api/drivers';

// The 'this.props.names' contains an array of names: ["John", "Susan", "John"].
// How would I iterate over the array, pull the names from this array, and then
// have those names rendered in a paragraph tag in a manner like:
// <p>John - Susan - John</p>

// So far I've attempted using template strings and the braces, {} , javascript
// injection. Doing this renders an empty paragraph. Please let know of the proper
// way to complete this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

export default class Riders extends React.Component {
  renderNames() {
    let empty = ``
    let names = this.props.names;
    let namesLength = names.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < namesLength; i++) {
      empty[i] = empty + `-` + ` ${empty[i]}`
    }
    return empty;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.renderNames}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your code.

First of all you need to call `renderNames` when rendering

```
<p>{this.renderNames()}</p>
```

Then `renderNames` implementation is incorrect.

1. `empty` is a string which are immutable in js. You can't mutate one using indices `empty[i] = something`
2. You should check that current element is not first. Since you don't want to insert separator before the first element
3. Whole loop is redundant. There is a special method `join` to join array of strings with a given separator.

So `renderNames` could be a simple as `return this.props.names.join(' - ')`

Comment: Thank you for responding this. I've just updated the code using the join method and it works! Using join definitely saved me from having to iterate through the array and then rendering the result to the screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### So this works now! Here's the implementation of the Join method as suggested by @Yury:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Drivers } from '../api/drivers';

export default class Riders extends React.Component {
  renderNames() {
    return this.props.riders.join(' - ');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.renderNames()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Reference to the "Join()" method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=control

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the JS .map method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control

With that you can just do something like:

```
let returnString = "";
this.props.names.map((item) => {
   //TODO: add something to check if it's the last item
   returnString += item + " - "
})
```

Comment: Why are you using `map` for this? Even if you somehow want to use iteration for this task there is a more sutable iterator `reduce`. Not to speak there is old good `join`.

Comment: All of these suggestions were great! Thank you guys for giving me further insight into solving this issue.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I didn't know about the reduce or join method until now! So I learned something :)

Answer (score -1):

As indicated you should use `{this.renderNames()}`. Check the below example

```
export default class React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderNames() {
    let empty = ``
    let names = this.props.names;
    let namesLength = names.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < namesLength; i++) {
      empty = empty + `-` + ` ${names[i]}`
    }

    return empty;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderNames()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would he need to bind `renderNames`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Because React uses the this keyword to reference the component context inside each class. @Kaeland uses the `this` keyword in `renderNames`(i.e this.props.names)

Comment: But he never pass this function as a callback. Binding in this case doesn't make sense. And in general binding to this has nothing to do with React. It is ES5 way to keep current context in callback.